# TeX \@for loop within a section title

Tags: macros, urls, loops, sections-paragraphs

I am creating a macro for turning a list of files into a comma-separated list of monospaced file names, and using it as a heading.

I have written a short script for doing so: MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\usepackage{url}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\edef\files{file_1.x,file_2.y,file_3.z}

\edef\comma{}%

\makeatletter
\@for\file:=\files\do{%
  \comma%
  \edef\comma{, }%
  \expandafter\url\expandafter{\file}%
}%

\end{document}
```

However, I cannot find how I can use the output as a heading: simply wrapping the `\@for` loop in a `\section{}` tag throws up *Undefined Control Sequence* errors. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that your loop works?

Comment: You want that, for each item in the list, `\section{\url{<item>}}` is issued?

Comment: @egreg No, that the whole list is a single heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `expl3` version with splitting of the list (using `\clist...`) and automatic setup as `\section`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}    
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\splitlist}[2]{%
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\csname #2\endcsname{\protect\url{##1}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\edef\files{file_1.x,file_2.y,file_3.z}

\splitlist{\files}{section}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Since the file list contains `_` characters, it's quite comfortable to go to `expl3` features and use a `\clist` variable as well. However, the last item mustn't have a `,` value, so don't use that (I added a `\int_compare` conditional for this).

In order to allow such commands in a command with moving arguments like `\section`, it's better to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` (instead of using the command with `\protect` all the time)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}    

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareRobustCommand{\splitlist}[1]{%
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \url{##1}%
    % is it the last item? If yes, add no , then!
    \int_compare:nNnT{\l_tmpa_int} < {\l_tmpb_int}{,~}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\edef\files{file_1.x,file_2.y,file_3.z}

\section{\splitlist{\files}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\use:c{#2}` is expl3 lingo for `\csname#2\endcsname`

Comment: How does clist work? Where's the best reference, so I can understand how this works?

Comment: @CharlieHarding: See the `interface3.pdf` documentation for `expl3` language settings. `\clist` is a LaTeX 3 variable datatype meant for comma separated lists.

Comment: I want to wrap the whole list in a section, rather than each individual item in a section (so the title is "file_1.x, file_2.y, file_3.z"). How would I do that?

Comment: @CharlieHarding: See the update please